# Kotlin non-local return from lambda passed as interface that extends `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0`

Tags: kotlin, return, higher-order-functions

## TL;DR

In Kotlin 1.3.61 (or newer), is there any way to make a non-local return from a lambda that is passed as the argument for a function parameter whose type is an interface that extends `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<Unit>`?

## Details

In the following Kotlin 1.3.61 code, I get compilation errors on the code lines after the comments that specify the errors.

It looks like I cannot make a non-local return from an enclosing function if the return is in a lambda passed to an inline function that accepts an interface that extends `Function0<Unit>`.

It works, however, if the receiving function accepts a `Function0<Unit>` (or a `() -> Unit`) instead of the sub-interface.

Is there any way to make a non-local return work from an interface that extends `Function0<Unit>`?

If not, is this either a bug in the Kotlin compiler, or is this a feature that is not yet supported by Kotlin?

If the latter, is there any existing request for enhancement?

If no request exists, is this a feature that could / should be supported by Kotlin?

```
inline fun a(x: () -> Unit) {
    x()
}

fun b(): Int {
    a {return 1}
    return 2
}

inline fun c(x: Function0<Unit>) {
    x()
}

fun d(): Int {
    c {return 3}
    return 4
}

interface F: Function0<Unit>

inline fun e(x: F) {
    x()
}

fun f(): Int {
    // ERROR
    // 'return' is not allowed here
    // Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> [ERROR : Return not allowed] but F was expected
    e {return 5}
    return 6
}

fun g(): Int {
    // ERRORS
    // Interface F does not have constructors
    // 'return' is not allowed here
    e(F {return 7})
    return 8
}

fun h(): Int {
    // ERROR
    // 'return' is not allowed here
    e({return 9} as F)
    return 0
}

println(b()) // properly prints 1 if code with errors is commented out
println(d()) // properly prints 3 if code with errors is commented out
println(f()) // should print 5
println(g()) // should print 7
println(h()) // should print 9
```

Comment: You call a function<``Unit``> - shouldn't this be ``Int``? Then return would be allowed. You currently return an integer to a ``Unit``.
Alternatively, as you explicitly want to use a unit-lambda, have you tried to return7@outer using a tag on the outer function?

Comment: `Function0<Unit>` is correct because the return in the argument lambda isn't a local return from the lambda; it's a non-local return that returns  from the enclosing function (e.g., `b()`, `d()`, etc.)  There is no error in `d()`, and `println(d())` correctly prints 3, if `f()`, `g()` & `h()` (plus calls to them) are commented out